# How to create system recovery partition from Windows 10

Tags: windows, cmd, recovery

I am writing a program for Microsoft refurbishers, and I would like to include a feature for creating a system recovery partition once all the necessary drivers are installed. The problem that I am running into is that it won't let me create the .wim file while the disk is mounted. When I try it gives me the error "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process". I have seen guides that say to boot to a windows installer, but that seems inefficient. Is it possible to create a backup of a running machine without booting to another drive? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am guessing that you are trying to use DISM.exe.  It doesn't support "hot image backups".. so no.  It cannot backup files that are locked,

Comment: Yes, I am. Is there an alternative to DISM?

Comment: Yes, there are others but they are 3rd party/proprietary and won't do anything more for you than DISM does (meaning also require reboot).  Perhaps someone else knows.. ANYONE?? .. ;^)

Comment: OK. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by creating a shadow copy of the drive. A free project using this approach was presented by the german c't magazine as a command script.
The project can be found and the scripts downloaded here:
[c't WIMage](https://www.heise.de/ct/artikel/c-t-WIMage-3863074.html).
Unfortunately this page is in german, but the script files may show you how it works.